# Spring-boot - how to restart a job per schedule

Tags: spring-batch, spring-boot

im working on a spring-boot app with spring-batch-2.2.5. - A simple app - read items from db and write to file. I have two issues when running the app:

1. The job runs fine once, but second time (after a fixed delay of 60s), seems to run, but says step status is Completed.
2. The second issue, is I randomly get WriterNotOpenException: Writer must be open before it can be written to. This happens on the first run. A few items are already written to, but then the exception happens.

   at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter.write(FlatFileItemWriter.java:255) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
   at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.writeItems(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:175) ~[spring-batch-core-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
   at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doWrite(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:151) ~[spring-batch-core-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
   at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.write(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:274) ~[spring-batch-core-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]

I ensured that JobParameters has a new timestamp for every run, but that does not seem to help.

Here is the code:

```
    public ItemReader<DomainClass> reader() {
    ArrayList<DomainClass> records = service.findrecords()
    return new IteratorItemReader<DomainClass>(records)
}

@Bean
public ItemProcessor<DomainClass, DomainClass> processor() {
    return new MyItemProcessor()
}

@Bean
public FlatFileItemWriter<DomainClass> writer() {
    FlatFileItemWriter flatFileItemWriter = new FlatFileItemWriter()
        DelimitedLineAggregator t = new DelimitedLineAggregator(delimiter: ',')
            t.setFieldExtractor(new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor(names: ["id", "description", "type", "date"]))
        flatFileItemWriter.setLineAggregator(t)
        flatFileItemWriter.setResource(new FileSystemResource('output.txt'))
    return flatFileItemWriter
}

@Bean
public Job  myJob(JobBuilderFactory jobs, Step s1) {
    Job job = jobs.get("myJob")
        .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
        .flow(s1).end().
        .build()

    return job
}

@Bean
public Step step1(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory, ItemReader<DomainClass> reader,
                                    ItemWriter<DomainClass> writer, ItemProcessor<DomainClass, DomainClass> processor) {
    logger.info "creating step1"
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
        .<DomainClass, DomainClass> chunk(10)
        .reader(reader)
        .processor(processor)
        .writer(writer)
        .build();
}
```

And here is the status on the second try: There is no error, but step says completed. Im not sure how to set the job to be "restartable" in the above code.

```
INFO  com.myapp.MyJobsApplication - Running MyJobs...
INFO  o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher - Job: [FlowJob: [name=myJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{time=1397603933056}]
INFO  o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler - Executing step: [step1]
INFO  o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher - Job: [FlowJob: [name=myJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{time=1397603933056}] and the following status: [COMPLETED]
```

Looking at the spring boot startup trace, it seems there are two threads trying to launch (main and pool-3-thread-1).. Not sure if thats an issue too:

```
18:17:46.441 [pool-3-thread-1] INFO  o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher - Job: [FlowJob: [name=myJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{time=1397603866386}]
18:17:46.463 [main] INFO  o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher - Job: [FlowJob: [name=myJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{run.id=2}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ther are maybe 3 questions there, so it might help to break it up. I can put questions back to you here to save space in comments...

- You have 2 executions in 2 threads because one is from a `@Scheduled` execution (I'm guessing by the thread ID), and one is from the "launch a single job on startup" rule implemented in  Spring Boot (you can switch that off - see the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-execute-spring-batch-jobs-on-startup), e.g. set "spring.batch.job.enabled=false").
- You seem surprised that the second execution completes successfully, but you don't say why. Is that a problem?
- If your process is going to be executing concurrent jobs (looks like it might be) you should make your stateful components `@StepScope`. The item writer looks like a good candidate for that based on the exception.

Comment: Thanks @Dave, I put it together for, I thought they are inter-related.

Adding the flag fixed problems 1 and 3. But yes, I am surprised that the second execution completes successfully. I need the same job to run again, because the records processed may be different. Process does not need to be concurrent, for now if i process one record at a time, thats sufficient.

Comment: I think you should add `@StepScope` anyway to be on the safe side. What is it that surprises you about the job completing? It looks normal to me.

Comment: Adding @ StepScope did it.

I was surprised (rather did not understand why) that the itemreader was not retrieving the new records, the job started and then reported Step is completed. Adding StepScope to the ItemReader works!

Thanks Dave!

Comment: If it's stateful, then it still has a memory of its first execution, so it probably thinks it has finished reading all the input records.